# Php Code for Inserting images in each row

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

I have need help in the below coding, right now it update the image every time i insert new trough form, i need it should update/insert image in each row not update the same image, kindly help .. code is below

```
<?PHP
if(isset($_POST['add_value'])){
    $sql ="INSERT INTO tb_special_offer (offer_price, offer_title, offer_desc, offer_link) VALUES ('"
        .addslashes($_REQUEST['offer_price'])."', '"
        .addslashes($_REQUEST['offer_title'])."', '"
        .addslashes($_REQUEST['offer_desc'])."', '"
        .addslashes($_REQUEST[offer_link])."')";
    $qry = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
    //Image

    if($_FILES['offer_img']['name']){
        $uploaded_image = $_FILES['offer_img']['name'];
        $imgpath = "userfiles/specialoffer/";
        if(file_exists($imgpath.$uploaded_image)) unlink($imgpath.$uploaded_image);
        if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['offer_img']['tmp_name'], $imgpath.$uploaded_image)){
            $errMsg= "UPLOAD ERROR..!!!".$_FILES['offer_img']['name'];
        }
        else {
            $sql = "update tb_special_offer set offer_img='$uploaded_image'   ";
            $qry = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
        }
    }

    header("Location: specialoffer?msg=Special Offer Added Successfully!");
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: SO are you saying that the code is not looping well when it takes the file from $_FILES?

Comment: yes . i am looking for the code that insert the image every time the code runs not just update the same image mean image with each row of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query means that all rows in your database get that image as value for the `offer_img` column. Update means just that: update a row.

If you want to update a specific row, not every row, do something like this:

```
update tb_special_offer set offer_img='$uploaded_image' where id=xxxx
```

But I suspect you want to use an INSERT query. As you've not provided any more info I cannot write it for you, but it should be easy. Just read [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html), but it boils down to something like

```
INSERT into tb_special_offer (offer_img) VALUES ('$uploaded_image')
```

Comment: i try that as well, my image int type is used now is Varchar, kindly send me insert comment that insert the image in each row each time i upload the form ..

Comment: My sql database is look like below 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tb_special_offer2` (
  `offer_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `offer_img` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `offer_title` varchar(500) default NULL,
  `offer_price` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `offer_desc` text NOT NULL,
  `offer_link` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY  (`offer_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=54 ;

Comment: thanks i done. i just replace the full insert quarry with update .. thanks for urs answers and help.. :)

Comment: If you think my answer was correct, please mark it as such. Otherwise, provide your own sollution in a separate answer. This will help future googlers :)  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work